# negative glue and hbox of same size do not cancel each other out

Tags: tex-core, boxes, plain-tex, box, glue

This code:

```
\hskip-1cm \hbox to 1cm{\hfil}\hbox to \hsize{\hfil Hello World}
\bye
```

yields

```
Overfull \hbox (20.0pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 1--2
```

Why is that? I would assume that applying negative glue and a horizontal box of the same size should cancel each other out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Paragraph indent is 20pt here.

```
\tracingoutput1
\noindent\hskip-1cm \hbox to 1cm{\hfil}\hbox to \hsize{\hfil Hello World}
\bye
```

Comment: Oh, of course. Thanks! I'm facing a more complicated problem at the moment and thought my issues is boiling down to this... Since I set \parindent0pt there, I at least know that I have another bug there